# Chrome Port fowrding close

Tags: google-chrome, tomcat, google-chrome-devtools

After tomcat installing on my laptop. In chrome port forwarding not enable. that show red color, before installing tomcat port forwarding running very good. yesterday i was removed tomcat then port forwarding not enable! what is the reason? anyone tells me. chrome show [like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuFeT.png)

Comment: Check the settings in More Tools -> Remote devices, setting Port forwarding enabled?

Comment: Yes I already checked and port forwarding is enabled!